# How to incorporate projected columns in scanner into new dataset partitioning

Tags: pyarrow

Let's say I load a dataset

```
myds=ds.dataset('mypath', format='parquet', partitioning='hive')
myds.schema
# On/Off_Peak: string
# area: string
# price: decimal128(8, 4)
# date: date32[day]
# hourbegin: int32
# hourend: int32
# inflation: string rename to Inflation
# Price_Type: string
# Reference_Year: int32
# Case: string
# region: string rename to Region
```

My end goal is to resave the dataset with the following projection:

```
projection={'Region':ds.field('region'),
            'Date':ds.field('date'),
            'isPeak':pc.equal(ds.field('On/Off_Peak'),ds.scalar('On')),
            'Hourbegin':ds.field('hourbegin'),
            'Hourend':ds.field('hourend'),
            'Inflation':ds.field('inflation'),
            'Price_Type':ds.field('Price_Type'),
            'Area':ds.field('area'),
            'Price':ds.field('price'),
            'Reference_Year':ds.field('Reference_Year'),
            'Case':ds.field('Case'),
            }
```

I make a scanner

```
scanner=myds.scanner(columns=projection)
```

Now I try to save my new dataset with

```
ds.write_dataset(scanner, 'newpath',
                partitioning=['Reference_Year', 'Case', 'Region'], partitioning_flavor='hive',
                format='parquet')
```

but I get

```
KeyError: 'Column Region does not exist in schema'
```

I can work around this by changing my `partitioning` to `['Reference_Year', 'Case', 'region']` to match the non-projected columns (and then later changing the name of all those directories) but is there a way to do it directly?

Suppose my partitioning needed the compute for more than just the column name changing.  Would I have to save a non-partitioned dataset in one step to get the new column and then do another save operation to create the partitioned dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** this bug has been fixed in pyarrow 10.0.0

It looks like a bug to me. It's as if `write_dataset` is looking at the [dataset_schema](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.html#pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.dataset_schema) rather than the [projected_schema](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.html#pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.projected_schema)

I think you can get around it by calling [to_reader](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.html#pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.to_reader) on the scanner.

```
table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [
        pa.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], pa.string()),
        pa.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], pa.string()),
    ],
    names=['region', "Other"]
)
table_dataset = ds.dataset(table)
columns={
    "Region": ds.field('region'),
    "Other": ds.field('Other'),
}
scanner = table_dataset.scanner(columns=columns)

ds.write_dataset(
    scanner.to_reader(), 
    'newpath',
    partitioning=['Region'], partitioning_flavor='hive',
    format='parquet')
```

I've reported the issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-17228)